# Story about a 4 dimensional creature attacking earth

Tags: story-identification

It's in a similar vein to *Flatland*, except in 3D. A 4D creature attacks Earth, using its 4-dimensional capabilities to its advantage. The protagonist defeats the creature by staking it to the ground. I'm fairly sure it's a well known story but the name evades me.

Comment: Can you remember any more details? Novel or short story? When did you read it? Was it written in English? Where was it set? What did the cover look like? Any clues could help!

Comment: Is it mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_dimension_in_literature) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatland#Adaptations_and_parodies)?

Comment: I believe it's a short story written in English, I can only say it was published in the 20th century (possibly before, but at least 50 years old). I have no more details than that, I'm afraid!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Might be ["The Monster From Nowhere"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58094) by Nelson Bond (1939). The detail of capturing a four-dimensional creature by impaling it is mentioned in a summary of the story by Michio Kaku in his book *Hyperspace*, on pages 75-77 which are available on google books [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=kFLiAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA75):

> Suddenly, the answer came to him: If a Flatlander were to try to capture our finger as it poked its way into Flatland, the Flatlander could stick a needle *through our finger*, painfully impaling it to the two-dimensional universe. Thus Patterson's strategy was to drive a spike through one of the blobs and impale the creature in our universe!

Comment: Yes! Thank you all. I would never have figured this out on my own.