# Old short story with multidimensional being/monster

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

As I remember the being from a multi dimensional universe seemed to change form as different parts of it interacted with our 3 dimensional universe.

I read it in the 1963 paperback edition of *The Best of Science Fiction* edited by Groff Conklin. [Here](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?4112) is a list of the contents.

The [1946 hardcover edition](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?4111) has stories that are not in the 1963 edition.

Anyone familiar with either edition should be able to identify the story.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

["The Monster from Nowhere"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58094), a short story by [Nelson S. Bond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelson_S._Bond), also the answer to [this old question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/106988/story-about-a-4-dimensional-creature-attacking-earth); originally published in [*Fantastic Adventures*, July 1939](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?58116+c), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Fantastic_Adventures_v01n02_1939-07_cape1736#page/n45/mode/2up). It starts on p. 291 of the 1963 paperback edition of [Groff Conklin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groff_Conklin)'s 1946 anthology [*The Best of Science Fiction*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?4112).

> The *thing* changed! As I watched, there seemed to be, at one time, a globular piece of matter twisting on the rod. An instant later, the globe had turned into a triangle—then into something remotely resembling a cube. It was constantly in motion; constantly in flux. But here is the curious part. It did not change shape slowly, as an amoeba, so that you could watch the sphere turn into an oblong; the oblong writhed into a formless blob of flesh. It made these changes instantaneously!

The "Flatlander" in the following excerpt is not a real character in the story, he's part of a thought experiment used to explain the concept.

> I said, "I told you I didn't have a scientific mind, Butch. What does all this mean?"
>
> Butch said patiently, "I have merely been establishing a thought-pattern, Len, so you can grasp the next step of my reasoning. Forget the Flatlander now—or, rather, try to think of *us* as being in his place!
>
> "Would we not, to a creature whose natural habitat is a higher plane than ours, appear much the same sort of projection as the Flatlander is to us?
>
> "Suppose a creature of this higher plane projected a portion of himself into *our* dimension—as I projected my finger into Flatland. We would not be able to see *all* of him, just as the Flatlander could not see all of us. We would see only a tri-dimensional cross-section of him; as the Flatlander saw a bi-dimensional cross-section of us!"
>
> This time I got it. I gasped:
>
> "Then you think that *thing* in the work-shed is a cross-section of a creature from the—"
>
> "Yes, Len. From the Fourth Dimension!"